# How to have csrf token from mobile in Laravel Application

Tags: php, web-services, cordova, laravel, csrf

I am building a cordova application,

In the Login Authentication

From Web, I am sending the `_token` , `email` & `password`.

But From Mobile, I can't generate `_token` as it is basically a `.html` file.

I planned to do a request in the form `document.ready` to a controller which will generate `_csrf` token. So that i can use that token for that request.

But it can be watched from browser's Network Tab.

How can set the csrf `_token` to the form without others knowledge (safe way).

Or How it can be deal without any vulnerabilities

Comment: You can use something like JWT (JSON Web Tokens), why reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: tokens are already generated by Laravel application, i want to you only those tokens, but it can generate only if the page is .php as i am building my app in cordova i can have only .html files .. That's y i can't generate tokens in default way,  Is JWT Safe ?

Comment: Yes very safe and since your using laravel may I recommend: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: The way to go is JWT ...

Comment: you can't create csrf token in html file.You can use get request to avoid csrf token

Comment: @Daan Thanks, Let me check it and use :)

Comment: @ImtiazPabel But Get is really bad way right.. !

Comment: then disable csrf token only for this method.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel You mean Disabling csrf token for post method ?

Comment: i mean disable csrf token only for that single post method.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel By setting something in headers of that particular request ?

Answer (score 1):

to disable csrf token for a specific url follow this.
First go to app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php then use your url to avoid csrf token

```
protected $except = [
    'my/url',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CSRF token checking in your laravel application for all routes. just open app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file and add '*' in $except array

Eg.

```
protected $except = [
        '*'
    ];
```

my VerifyCsrfToken.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '*'
    ];
}
```